# gazebo and timer.py(rate.sleep)

Tags: ros, gazebo, rospy, sleep, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm running yappi to profile the performance of my node written in python.

The node has:

- 3 timers for controller loops. (2 at 500Hz and 1 at 100Hz)
- 2 publisher (60Hz for /gazebo/set_model_state and 100Hz)
- 2 subscriber

When Gazebo is not running, the profiler shows 35.15% time is spent on Rate.sleep()

When Gazebo is running, the profiler shows 46.92% time is spent on Rate.sleep(). In particular, 16.06% is spent on _Condition.wait from threading.py, which doesn't not show up in previous scenario. Nothing change even when I comment out any code related to publishing /gazebo/set_model_state.

I also notice when Gazebo is running, my node that usually takes up ~50% CPU now runs at ~100%. Also the controller loops don't seem to be running on time.

Question is why my node impacted by Gazebo?
I should also mention that because I want to run yappi, I'm not using rosrun to launch the node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285076/gazebo-and-timer.py(rate.sleep)/) by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A word of warning (so not an answer): using Python here on a general purpose OS with no deterministic scheduling is never going to have all of your loops run correctly (ie: on schedule). Python could have the least influence on that, but it's not going to help.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0